# IntelliJ IDE always launches in presentation mode

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

My IntelliJ IDE defaults to the "Presentation" view when opened, and I don't want to reset all my settings to default. How do I reset the IDE to the default view?

Comment: You can have a workaround of this problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65098508/3145960

Comment: @ReazMurshed that's different than the issue presented here; this is where the IDE opens in presentation view every time it is launched.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested on PHPStorm 2018.3, Windows 10 64-bit**

With the IDE off, go to `C:\Users\<myuser>\.PhpStorm2018.3\config\jba_config\win.ui.lnf.xml`, and set `<option name="presentationMode" value="true" />` to false.

Answer (score 0):

#### PHPStorm 2023.2 Windows 11

If using ***'New UI'***, ***unsync*** the theme with the OS (make sure box is unchecked):

[image]